# geometric intuition behind a homeomorphism

Tags: general-topology, intuition, visualization

I've read that

> geometrically speaking, a homeomorphism from $M$ to $N$ is a bijection that can bend, twist, stretch and wrinkle the space $M$ to make it coincide with $N$ but it cannot rip, puncture, shred or pulverize $M$ in the process.

I have difficulty to see why a continuous bijection (with continuous inverse) can be seen as doing such things. Can someone elaborate or give me ways to visualize it?

Comment: They should also say that it can not glue. When you bend and stretch nearby points stay nearby, when you rip or puncture, they are pulled apart, no matter how close they were. So ripping is discontinuous. When you glue, distant points become nearby, so the inverse must rip them apart, and it will be discontinuous.

Comment: What specific part can't you visualize?

Comment: The essential thing is that a homeomorphism gives one-to-one correspondence between the points of the two spaces so that a subset on one side will be a neighborhood of a point iff the corresponding subset on the other side is a neighborhood of the corresponding point.